# Hyperref with internal link toward bib url entry

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, hyperref, natbib, urls

When using the `hypperref` package, with the `\citet{}` commandline from `natbib`, the internal link send to the bibliography at the end of the document. Is there anyway to configure `hyperref` or `natbib` such that a browser open directly the url contained in the bib entry of the bibliography (called in my case adsurl) ?

An example of a bib entry of my bibliography can be found below:

```
@ARTICLE{Ayres(1981),
    author = {{Ayres}, T.~R. and {Marstad}, N.~C. and {Linsky}, J.~L.},
    title = "{Outer atmospheres of cool stars. IX. A survey of ultraviolet emission from F-K dwarfs and giants with the IUE.}",
    journal = {apj},
    keywords = {Chromosphere, Cool Stars, Dwarf Stars, F Stars, G Stars, Giant Stars, K Stars, Stellar Atmospheres, Ultraviolet Astronomy, Ultraviolet Spectra, Emission Spectra, Iue, Line Spectra, Protostars, Solar Wind, Stellar Coronas, Stellar Spectra, Astronomy},
    year = 1981,
    month = jul,
    volume = {247},
    pages = {545-559},
    doi = {10.1086/159065},
    adsurl = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1981ApJ...247..545A},
    adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

[image]

Comment: natbib based styles typically don't give access to the needed data. You would need biblatex for this.

Comment: So you want the citation callout/hypertarget to point straight to some external site in case the bibliographic entry contains a suitable field (such as `adsurl`) but to point to the formatted entry in the bibliography in case no such field is provided? And what action should be taken if you happen to be offline while you're reading the paper in pdf format? Please advise.

Comment: Exactly, but it should always point to the url because such a field is always available. If there is no internet the hyperlink should open try to open the link but this is not to latex to deal with it. 
@UlrikeFischer Do you know how to do it with bib latex ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way to do this with `natbib` (or any BibTeX-based bibliography setup), because `natbib`/BibTeX does not access to the entry URLs in the citations.

One way to resolve this might be to query the field with `usebib`. Another solution would be to patch the used `.bst` style to also export the link URLs in a usable format.

With `biblatex` things are easier, because all entry data is available at any time.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{\usebibmacro{citelink}{#1}}

\newbibmacro*{citelink}[1]{%
  \iffieldundef{doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}
       {\bibhyperref{#1}}
       {\href{\thefield{urlraw}}{#1}}}
    {\href{https://doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,ctan,worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```